Is there any way to seperate titles with their orders and normal paragraphs in a openXML for docx
I am trying to seperate types of paragraphs similar to html tags like h1, h2 or p.
I opened a docx's xml and searched for a xml tag that indicates such types. However, I couldn't find a solution. It seemed like everything was in paragraph tag and there were no further indication for it's type or order.

Hi @GokalpG, have your check the official Sample code? How is your xml like? And what you have done from now on?
